# Replace Firebase Authentication callbacks with Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am using Firebase phone Authentication.

```
auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener { task->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.d("TAG", "success")
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Success",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                task.exception?.message ?: "Error on verifying",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            task.message.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
```

One of the important motive of `Coroutine` is to replace callbacks.
How can I replace these callbacks like `addOnCompleteListener`, `addOnFailureListener` etc. with Kotlin Coroutine. Like we do with retrofit, see [example here](https://github.com/Chandra-Sekhar-Bala/MVVM-ToDo/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/sekhar/todo/app/ShowMotivation/MotivationViewModel.kt) from line no 36.

Comment: If you want at some point in time to implement Firebase sign-in with Google using Kotlin Coroutine, then this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Answer (score 2):

There is [`await`](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#kotlin_coroutine) method on `Task` object which is `suspend`, it can be called from a coroutine:

```
viewModelScope.launch { // launching a coroutine
    try {
        val authResult: AuthResult =  auth.signInWithCredential(credential).await()
        // ...
        
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // ... handle failures
    }
}
```

To launch a coroutine `viewModelScope` can be used in a `ViewModel` class, or `lifecycleScope` in `Activity`/`Fragment`.